# How can I find all solutions of a complicated expression in a desired interval with Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, complex, special-functions

I have an expression which is a combination of Bessel functions:

```
 eq[k_, ω_] = 0.004 k Sqrt[-k^2 + ω^2] (k^2 + ω^2 + 
k ω (-2 + 1.3*10^(-14) ω^2)) BesselJ[1, √((0.002 k - 
    0.002 ω + ω (-0.9 k + 0.0003/(
       k - ω) + ω) (-k^2 + ω^2) (-1 + 
       0.0004/(-0.9 k + ω)^2))/(0.002 - ω (-k + 
       0.0003/(k - ω) + ω) (1 + 
       0.01/(-0.001 + 
        5 (-k + ω)^2) - (0.01 (0.002 k^2 (-k + 0.0003/(
              k - ω) + ω)))/((-0.001 + (-k + ω)^2) (0.002 - ω^2 (-0.9 k + 0.0003/(
               k - ω) + ω))))))] ((k^2 - 
   0.7 ω^2) BesselJ[1, 
  2 Sqrt[-k^2 + 0.5 ω^2]] BesselY[1, 
  1.5 Sqrt[-k^2 + 0.5 ω^2]] + 
0.3 k^2 BesselJ[1, 1.5 Sqrt[-k^2 + 0.5 ω^2]] BesselY[1, 
  2 Sqrt[-k^2 + 0.5 ω^2]]) (BesselJ[1, 
  1.5 Sqrt[-k^2 + ω^2]] BesselY[1, 
  Sqrt[-k^2 + ω^2]] - 
BesselJ[1, Sqrt[-k^2 + ω^2]] BesselY[1, 
  1.5 Sqrt[-k^2 + ω^2]])
```

[image: Form of equation]

I want to find root of this equation for a specified value of `k=1`. By plotting this equation I realized that this equation acquire real and imaginary values so I tried the `FindRoot`& `NSove` & `Reduce`commands while restricting the range of `/[Omega]` as follow:

```
Reduce[eq[1,/[Omega]==0 && -1<Re[ω]<1 && -1<Im[ω]<1,ω]
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work at all.
Can any one resolve this problem for me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, `FindRoot[eq[1, w], {w, 0}]` works, and returns $$w=0.00222463$$ with some small imaginary value

Comment: Why do you mean by "it doesn't work at all". You get no answer, an error, it churns indefinitely...? Your `Reduce` expression contains syntax errors. Generally, I would suspect that your expression is too complicated to attempt to get a general solution with `Solve` and `Reduce`. `NSolve` mostly deals with polynomial equations anyway, so it won't help much here. You are left with `FindRoot`, which works just fine in your case, as @yohbs showed above, but won't give you *all* solutions.

Comment: I know FindRoot command (with the above mentioned  format) is useful to seek for a single root but I can't find all roots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using your definition of `eq`, if you try `Solve` even without imposing conditions on `ω`, you obtain the following error:

```
Solve[eq[1, ω] == 0, ω]
```

> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

**This is very valuable information!** *Mathematica* is really giving you a big pointer in the right direction here.

Typically Solve will attempt to `Rationalize` a system with inexact coefficients, in hopes of obtaining something it can deal with more easily. However, in your case this rationalization step seems to have failed. Upon inspection of your coefficients, this is because of the value of one particularly small coefficient in your expression. In fact, see what happens if we attempt the rationalization by hand:

```
Rationalize[eq[1, ω]]
```

`(1/250)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]*(1 + ω^2 + ω*(-2 + 1.3*^-14*ω^2))*BesselJ[1, Sqrt[(1/500 - ω/500 + (-1 + 1/(2500*(-(9/10) + ω)^2))*ω*(-(9/10) + 3/(10000*(1 - ω)) + ω)*(-1 + ω^2))/(1/500 - ω*(-1 + 3/(10000*(1 - ω)) + ω)*(1 + 1/(100*(-(1/1000) + 5*(-1 + ω)^2)) - (-1 + 3/(10000*(1 - ω)) + ω)/(50000*(-(1/1000) + (-1 + ω)^2)*(1/500 - ω^2*(-(9/10) + 3/(10000*(1 - ω)) + ω)))))]]*((1 - (7*ω^2)/10)*BesselJ[1, 2*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2/2]]*BesselY[1, (3/2)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2/2]] + (3/10)*BesselJ[1, (3/2)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2/2]]*BesselY[1, 2*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2/2]])*(BesselJ[1, (3/2)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]]*BesselY[1, Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]] - BesselJ[1, Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]]*BesselY[1, (3/2)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]])`

Almost everything was transformed into a rational number, *except the very small* $1.3\times 10^{-14}$ *value*, which is too small for `Rationalize`'s default tolerance (see its [documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html), under "Details").

However, we can force every number to a rational representation by setting this tolerance to $0$:

```
Rationalize[eq[1, ω], 0]
```

`(1/250)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]*(1 + ω^2 + ω*(-2 + (13*ω^2)/1000000000000000))*BesselJ[1, Sqrt[(1/500 - ω/500 + (-1 + 1/(2500*(-(9/10) + ω)^2))*ω*(-(9/10) + 3/(10000*(1 - ω)) + ω)*(-1 + ω^2))/(1/500 - ω*(-1 + 3/(10000*(1 - ω)) + ω)*(1 + 1/(100*(-(1/1000) + 5*(-1 + ω)^2)) - (-1 + 3/(10000*(1 - ω)) + ω)/(50000*(-(1/1000) + (-1 + ω)^2)*(1/500 - ω^2*(-(9/10) + 3/(10000*(1 - ω)) + ω)))))]]*((1 - (7*ω^2)/10)*BesselJ[1, 2*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2/2]]*BesselY[1, (3/2)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2/2]] + (3/10)*BesselJ[1, (3/2)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2/2]]*BesselY[1, 2*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2/2]])*(BesselJ[1, (3/2)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]]*BesselY[1, Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]] - BesselJ[1, Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]]*BesselY[1, (3/2)*Sqrt[-1 + ω^2]])`

This should help `Solve` for your problem:

```
Solve[Rationalize[eq[1, ω], 0] == 0, ω, Cubics -> False, Quartics -> False]
```

Not specifying a domain implicitly allows for complex solutions; this quickly evaluates to give nine solutions, expressed as `Root` objects. A **numerical estimate** of those solutions can be obtained with:

```
numsolns = Chop[N[solns]]

(* Out:
{ {ω -> -7.69231*10^13}, {ω -> 1. - 1.14018*10^-7 I}, 
  {ω -> 1. + 1.14018*10^-7 I}, {ω -> -1.00105}, {ω -> 0.00222463}, 
  {ω -> 0.8793}, {ω -> 0.897109}, {ω -> 0.91953}, {ω -> 1.00289} }
*)
```

Of course you can substitute those back into `eq[1, ω]` to check that they are actual roots for that expression:

```
Chop[eq[1, ω] /. numsolns]

(*Out: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

---

Finally, you can select those solutions whose real and imaginary parts are in the interval $[-1,1]$ using e.g. `Select`:

```
Select[ω /. numsolns, -1 < Re[#] < 1 && -1 < Im[#] < 1 &]

(* Out:
{1. - 1.14018*10^-7 I, 1. + 1.14018*10^-7 I, 0.00222463, 0.8793, 0.897109, 0.91953}
*)
```

---

### A different take:

That very small coefficient is odd in comparison to all others in the OP's expression. I had wondered if it was just a **leftover from roundoff errors**. @Guesswhoitis brought up the very same point, so it is worth exploring.

We can `Chop` that tiny value off, `Rationalize` the resulting expression, and feed it to `Solve`:

```
choppedeq[k_, ω_] = Chop[eq[k, ω]];

choppedsolns = Solve[Rationalize[choppedeq[1, ω]] == 0, ω];
numchoppedsolns = ω /. N@choppedsolns
```

(* Out: {-1.00105, 0.00222463, 0.8793, 0.897109, 0.91953, 1.00289} *)

In this case `Solve` returns six `Root` objects, whose approximate numerical values are shown above. **The solutions are all real! One wonders about the original problem...**

We can also take a look at the expression itself after removing that small value:

```
GraphicsGrid@ With[
  {opts = Sequence[Evaluated -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], Red, Point[{#, 0} & /@ numchoppedsolns]}]},
  {
   {Plot[Through[{Abs, Re, Im}[choppedeq[1, ω]]], {ω, -1.1, 1.1}, opts, AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRange -> 0.002], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
    Plot[Through[{Abs, Re, Im}[choppedeq[1, ω]]], {ω, #1, #2}, opts, ImageSize -> 250] & @@@ {{-1.1, -.9}, {0, 0.005}, {0.87, 0.93}, {0.98, 1.02}}
  }
]
```

[image: grid of solutions]

Comment: Sometimes, one just has to read error messages carefully instead of tearing your hair out after seeing them… :) But, I now wonder whether that tiny constant is actually a characteristic of the system, or mere rounding error.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I wondered the same thing. I had chopped that tiny constant off just for fun, and the results are wildly different, but in the interest of answering the question as faithfully as possible, I left those off. I'll dig them back up and include them in the answer.

Comment: "the results are wildly different" - a huge red flag, in my book. It can be that OP's actual problem is badly scaled, or worse, ill-conditioned. [Wilkinson's classic example](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Wilkinson.pdf) comes to mind…

Comment: Here's another experiment you can try: what if you replace `Rationalize[#, 0] &` with `SetPrecision[#, ∞] &`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I ran that just now, and there is no difference between the solutions found for the `Rationalize[#, 0]&` expression and the `SetPrecision[#, Infinity]&`. What was your reasoning in these cases though? Numerical instability? I would have thought that something would have been quite wrong if they had been different.

Comment: "no difference" - that's for the system with the tiny constant, yes?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. correct, the original system from the OP's question

Comment: At the very least, from your results, it seems that four of the roots are not very sensitive to perturbation. This is indeed similar to Wilkinson's example: some of the roots don't change much after perturbation, but some explode in the complex plane.

Comment: **MacroB** , **Guess who it is** Thank you for your great discussion.

Comment: As @MacroB suggested, I used `Chop` command to eliminate that small coefficient. But I think there is a small problem here: By using `Solve` command, Mathematica suggest to use `Reduce` for finding all root. I tried 'Reduce' command again but it delivers nothing. I wrote the following code to see if all the roots are found by `Solve` or not:

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Plot[{Re[choppedeq[1, \[Omega]]], 
   Im[choppedeq[1, \[Omega]]]}, {\[Omega], \[Alpha], \[Alpha] + 0.2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{\[Alpha], \[Alpha] + .2}, {-.1, .1}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], {\[Alpha], -5, 5}]` . I know that if both of `Re` & `Im` parts `choppedeq` become zero on a point, that point is a root of 'choppedeq' too. So I understand that there are some roots that `Solve` cant find them. Can you provide any more guide...?

Comment: @user2345837 if you think that my answer above adequately addresses your problem, would you consider formally accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark next to it?

Comment: @MarcoB :) Here you are!

Comment: @user2345837 Thank you! I appreciate it, and hope the answer was useful.